# Arrays in Bash Shell

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell

I want to write a shell script to get the following output:

```
$ Enter String: a2b3

aabbb
```

I tried using `for` loops and arrays, but the loop count messes with the array index and leaves null elements within the array, making it impossible to print out the array as required.

The script used:

```
echo "Enter your alphanumeric string: "
read a
n=${#a}

for (( i=0;i<n;i++ ))
do
string[i]=${a:i:1}

if [[ ${string[i]} =~ [a-zA-Z] ]]
then
alpha[i]=${string[i]}
elif [[ ${string[i]} =~ [0-9] ]]
then

if [[ ${string[i+1]} =~ [0-9] ]]
then
num[i]=${string[i]}${string[i+1]}
elif ! [[ ${string[i+1]} =~ [0-9] ]]
then
num[i]=${string[i]}
fi

fi
done

n=${#num[*]}
for (( i=0;i<n;i++ ))
do
echo num[$i] = ${num[i]}
done

n=${#alpha[*]}
for (( i=0;i<n;i++ ))
do
echo alpha[$i] = ${alpha[i]}
done
```

The output I get for the same:

```
$ sh Q1.sh
Enter your alphanumeric string: 
a6b3
num[0] =
num[1] = 6
alpha[0] = a
alpha[1] =
```

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/60932427/7552

Answer (score 0):

A better way to append an element to an array is with `array+=(...)`. Then you don't have to worry about having the correct index on the left-hand side.

```
alpha+=("${string[i]}")
```

```
num+=("${string[i]}" "${string[i+1]}")
```

Comment: Thank You for the solution. But am afraid it doesn't resolve the problem completely. `Enter your alphanumeric string: 
v4b3
num[0] = 4
num[1] = 3
alpha[0] = v
alpha[1] = b
vvvvbbb 
**$ sh Q1.sh**
Enter your alphanumeric string: 
a12b20
num[0] = 1
num[1] = 2
num[2] = 2
num[3] = 0
alpha[0] = a
alpha[1] = b
abb`

Comment: Handling two-digit numbers is a different question.

Comment: It would be great then, if you could help me with that too. Thank You.

Comment: I recommend posting it as a separate question. It requires a different, more complicated answer, and Stack Overflow isn't designed for back-and-forth debugging sessions tackling multiple problems.