# Handling two-digit numbers as a single element in arrays

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell

I want to write a shell script to get the following output:

```
$ Enter String: a2b3

aabbb
```

I've used arrays within `for` loops, but it always fails to append two-digit values from the string, as a single element into the array. It always gets stored as two separate elements in the array.

The script used:

```
echo "Enter your alphanumeric string: "
read a
n=${#a}

for (( i=0;i<n;i++ ))
do
string[i]=${a:i:1}

if [[ ${string[i]} =~ [a-zA-Z] ]]
then
alpha+=("${string[i]}")
elif [[ ${string[i]} =~ [0-9] ]]
then

if [[ ${string[i+1]} =~ [0-9] ]]
then
num+=${string[i]}${string[i+1]}
elif ! [[ ${string[i+1]} =~ [0-9] ]]
then
num+=("${string[i]}")
fi

fi
done

n=${#num[*]}
for (( i=0;i<n;i++ ))
do
echo num[$i] = ${num[i]}
done

n=${#alpha[*]}
for (( i=0;i<n;i++ ))
do
echo alpha[$i] = ${alpha[i]}
done

n=${#alpha[*]}
for (( i=0;i<n;i++ ))
do
y=${num[i]}
for (( j=0;j<y;j++ ))
do
echo -ne ${alpha[i]}
done
done
echo " "
```

The output I get for the same:

```
$ sh Q1.sh
Enter your alphanumeric string: 
a12b20
num[0] = 1
num[1] = 2
num[2] = 2
num[3] = 0
alpha[0] = a
alpha[1] = b
abb
```

I need the value `12` to be stored as a single element `num[0]` rather than as two individual elements, `num[0]=1`, `num[1]=2`. Same with the value `20`.

Please help me out here....thank you in advance.

Comment: This needs more details. Like, is there a number after every letter or is an input like `abc3` possible? If yes, what is the expected output for that? `abcabcabc` or `abccc`?

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk:

```
gawk '{n=split($0,a,/[0-9]+/,s);for(i=1;i<=n;i++){for(j=1;j<=s[i];j++)printf a[i]}}'
```

For example,

```
$ echo "A10b2"|gawk '{n=split($0,a,/[0-9]+/,s);for(i=1;i<=n;i++){for(j=1;j<=s[i];j++)printf a[i]}}'
AAAAAAAAAAbb
```

To understand what `gawk` is doing, check out split function in [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#String-Functions).

---

If you want to stick to bash, here is another way to do it:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter your alphanumeric string: " a
mapfile -t array < <(echo "$a"|grep -Eo "[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+")
for x in "${array[@]}"; do
    letters=${x%%[0-9]*}
    digits=${x##*[a-z]}
    printf "%0.s$letters" $(seq 1 $digits)
done
echo
```

`grep` gets the sequences (letters,digits) from the string and `mapfile` generates an array from the output. For `a20b30`, you get an array with elements `a20` and `b30`.

Then for each element of the array, you get the `letters` and `digits` and print the former `digits` times.

Output example:

```
$ bash alpha.sh
Enter your alphanumeric string: x3zx10n2
xxxzxzxzxzxzxzxzxzxzxzxnn
```

I got the `printf` idea from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17030976).

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier to use a more advanced programming language, e.g. Perl:

```
$ perl -we 'print $1, $2 x $3
                while $ARGV[0] =~ /([^0-9]*)([^0-9])([0-9]+)/g
    ' a1b1c3de11
abcccdeeeeeeeeeee
```

But, if you you like torturing yourself in bash, keep a flag that tells you what you're parsing currently - either a string, or a number. Based on that, accumulate the characters in the correct array. Keep a separate index for the characters in the input and the element of the output, increase the latter when you start parsing a string after having parsed a number.

```
current=string

j=0

for (( i=0;i<n;i++ )) ; do
    if [[ ${a:i:1} == [0-9] ]] ; then
        [[ $current == string ]]
        current=num
        num[j]+=${a:i:1}
    else
        [[ $current == num ]] && (( ++j ))
        current=string
        alpha[j]+=${a:i:1}
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're reading the input character by character, you'll need to use a little state machine:

- prev char was alpha, this char is alpha -> do something
- prev char was alpha, this char is digit -> do something
- etc

You might have better luck with using a regex

```sh
while [[ $input =~ ([[:alpha:]])([[:digit:]]+) ]]; do
    char=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    num=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    input_prefix=${input%%${BASH_REMATCH[0]}*}
    input_suffix=${input#*${BASH_REMATCH[0]}}
    # then reconstruct $input using those pieces
done
```

Unfortunately bash has no mechanism for "get me all the matches of this regex" so you're stuck with a while loop.